# Play 2.4 - differences in GuiceApplicationBuilder, GuiceApplicationLoader, and GuiceInjectorBuilder

Tags: java, playframework

Can someone please explain the differences between GuiceApplicationBuilder, GuiceApplicationLoader, and GuiceInjectorBuilder. I read the docs ([JavaTestingWithGuice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWithGuice) and [JavaFunctionalTest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFunctionalTest)) but somehow I still don't understand how to use them.